# How to do a mapping of an excel file using c#

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I wanted to do a mapping of an excel file but with the columns in a certain way.
As for example I have an exel file where the second column (of the excel file) has to be referenced there is 1 column of the sql database.

This is the `Form` I'm using:
[image]

I already have the sql search done I just wanted to know how I can put in the combobox the name of the columns in the excel file.

This is the code I am using to search the excel file:

```
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls", ValidateNames = true })
        {
            DataSet result;
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
                reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                result = reader.AsDataSet();
                comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables) comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                reader.Close();

                string ConecçãoDB = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConecçaoDB"].ConnectionString;
                string Table = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["table"];

                string ssqltable = Table;

                string ssqlconnectionstring = ConecçãoDB;

                filename = ofd.FileName;
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(filename));
                var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
                var conexao = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                var sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + comboBox1.SelectedText + "$]";
                string sclearsql = "delete from " + ssqltable;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having - the actual databinding into the combobox itself?  What steps have you taken so far to try this, or are you stuck?

Comment: @LightCC I'm stuck on adding the data to combobox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating my answer based on your latest comment as I misunderstood what you need.

You need to access Excel object model and after that you will have full and easy control over Excel data.

For a solid and simple answer refer to :

[Microsoft Interop: Excel Column Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721161/microsoft-interop-excel-column-names)

When using the suggested code make sure you add the following reference to your code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Remember the provided answer there puts the column names in a generic list of strings.

After that you have to bind it to combo box:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource=columnNames ;
comboBox1.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: what you mean with "Here add your code to populate Dataset ds from the Database"

Comment: So let say your Excel file has 3 columns A,B,C, in Combox you want to see 
A,B,C(On C# Webform)? please confirm.

Comment: Yes , thats what I need

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your question, now I know what you want. Updating my answer.

Comment: Is this the best way to do what I need?

Comment: In my view, this is the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: First, you need to add that reference to the project references. Go to project menu and then add reference. Then on right-hand side click on COM and then find Microsoft Excel xx.x Object Library.